# Access the nested elements in table and change the height of table cell in html CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

Really confused about nesting elements.
How to target **td** 1 and **td** 3  in each row (in following code), and also how to reduce the height of **each td cell** of the table plus how to change the size i.e. the width and height of  of the table.

`

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

`

I want to achieve the following type of table, how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: how does your table look like now? where is your html?

Comment: For how to select 1 and 3 td element see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp The height of the nodes td is inherited from their respective parent element tr. You can find how to change the width and height attributes in the website above.

Comment: going to post that html but how to target the **1** and **2** td element in each row ,in above code?@NawedKhan

Comment: tr td:first-child will get you td1 and td3 as they are the First td (child) of their parent TRs